How to bring an Excel table to latex with multiple hierarchies
I have the following case:
A MS Excel spreadsheet has been created that shows a hierarchy of classifications on the left side. On the right side the number of assignments needs to be shown.
How can I bring this spreadsheet from Excel to Latex?
I tried it, but it did not look like a "table of contents" (which is similarly structured: hierarchical text on the left, numbers on the right).
Attached is the Excel file with sample values and also my current Latex file.
Any ideas?
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{todo}


%opening
\title{Test}
\author{Thomas}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{Test CodeBook Table}\label{Appendix:CodeBook}
This appendix contains all categories and their definitions and     was created during the QCA.

\todo{Must be filled at the end of the work}


\begin{longtable}[l]{llllll}
\caption{The code book, exported from Tool X on December 10th, 2024.}
\label{tab:CodeBook}\\
\hline

\textbf{\makecell[l]{\multicolumn{5}{l}{List of codes}}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Frequency \\of occurrence}} \\

\hhline{======}
\endfirsthead
%
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{Table \thetable\ continued from previous page} \\
\textbf{\makecell[l]{\multicolumn{5}{l}{List of codes}}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Frequency \\of occurrence}} \\
\hhline{======}
\endhead
%

\multicolumn{5}{l}{Codesystem} &
300 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{other ideas for case companies} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Product Roadmap manifesto} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{SPM Gateway} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Company's release cycle} &
2 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Market where Product is sold} &
2 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{How many persons working in the area of SPM in your   firm?} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Software development process used} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{SCRUM} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{good quotes} &
1 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Unsure} &
0 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Number of employees} &
3 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Introduction, filling text passages} &
0 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Deployment} &
0 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Software as a service} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{On-Premise installations} &
2 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{FQ1: Have you ever been involved in software product   management in this firm?} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{no} &
0 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{yes} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q1: How is software product management organized in   your company?} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Wishlist and problem list} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bi-weekly meetings} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Quarterly meetings} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Own organisational unit} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Coffe break sessions} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Tools used for PM} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{by PM Team} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{by Joure Fixe} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q2: Who is responsible for software product   management in your company?} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q3: What kind of software you're company is   developing?} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Standardized SaaS Software with customizations} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Other} &
0 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Standardized software with customizations} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Off-the-shelf software / Standard software} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Individual Software} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q4: What do you understand by ``standard software''?} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{SQ1: Imagine the following: Suppose a customer asks   for a new requirement. What would have to happen in sequence for the requir} &
4 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{SQ2: Another customer asks for a new requirement.   What would have to happen in sequence for the requirement to become a cust} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Parameters and options} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ1: What drives external and internal investment in   software products?} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{drivers for external investments} &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
Process simplification &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
added monetary value &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
added value in time &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
Absolute necessity for customer &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Drivers for internal investments} &
3 \\
&
&
&
&
Required functionality on the market &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
Initial development of the software product &
1 \\
&
&
&
&
Clear differentiation from competitors &
1 \\
&
&
&
&
Aiming for technological leadership &
2 \\
&
&
&
&
Legal requirements and changes &
1 \\
&
&
&
&
technological trends &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q5: How do you finance standard software product   development?} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Initial development financed by owners} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{One-time cost contributions for new customers} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Others} &
0 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Financed from current operations / from cash flow} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Based on current license revenues} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Customer has to buy a concrete functionality} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q6: What happens if decision will be felt that a   feature must not be part of you're companies standard product?} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q7: Who will be the person(s) who decides which   features have to be included in your standardized software?} &
5 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Support} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Marketing} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Operations} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Development} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Others} &
0 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{The owner(s) of the company} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Customers} &
0 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Account managers} &
5 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Software product managers} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Board members} &
5 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q8: Is there a systematic approach or process to   creating standard extensions based on previously created customizations?} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{only for macro tasks} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ12: How do customer-specific adaptations lead to   extensions of the product standard?} &
3 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{This case is not supported} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ3: Which and why internal/external requested   features trigger internal investments?} &
2 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ2: How are decisions made about the standard   relevance of features in software products?} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{SQ3: Think about the last two years: What were the   decision-making processes in your company regarding the inclusion of featur} &
2 \\
&
\multicolumn{4}{l}{FQ2: Are you involved in software release planning   process?} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{How do you align your relases to your roadmap?} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q9: Does your company have a software release plan?   Could you make this available?} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{yes, release plan exists, but is not public} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{no} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{yes} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q10: Does your company have written guidelines for   the software product roadmapping process?    If so, can you provide them?} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{yes, guidelines exist} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Q11: On a scale of 1-10, how important is software   release management to you personally? (Scale 1-10, 1=not important, 10=ver} &
3 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ6a: What cycles are used for concrete release   plans?} &
8 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{continous with a weekly cylce, meetings every second   week} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{half-year release plan} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ7a: Who approves updated specific release   plans?} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bi-weekly meeting members} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Development} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Sales} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Product Managers} &
2 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Board members} &
1 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Nobody} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ9a: What marks a software release plan as   complete? What are the goals and interests in these areas?} &
4 \\
&
&
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{KQ9a2 What are the goals and interests of   steakholders during definition of a software release plan?} &
1 \\
&
&
\multicolumn{3}{l}{KQ10: What conflicts have arisen in the area of   software product roadmapping and software release planning? What caused these   p} &
4 \\



\hline
\end{longtable} 



\end{document}


Your latex file seems to be missing. Please copy it into your question.

I've uploaded it now.

Doesn't compile for me

I would just add different amounts of \hspace instead of using \multicolumn.

If indenting is all you want to do, here is one way to do it:

table with two columns
use \hspace{} for indenting
absorb those in \newcommands \ina, \inb, \inc
fine-tune the horizontal spaces there, in one-place-only


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~
\newcommand\ina[0]{\hspace{2em}}
\newcommand\inb[0]{\hspace{4em}}
\newcommand\inc[0]{\hspace{6em}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
 \toprule
 Liste der Codes&   Häufigkeit\\
 \midrule
 Codesystem                     & 300\\
 \ina{}other ideas for case companies   &   1\\
 \ina{}Product Roadmap manifesto        &   1\\
 \inb SCRUM                     &   1\\
 \midrule
 \ina FQ1: Have you ever \dots  & 2\\
 \inb Q1: How is software \dots & 3\\
 \inc wishlist                  & 1\\
 \inc biweekly \dots    & 2\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 
\end{document}


Thank you so much for your ideas and solutions! Works fine! Great!
Best regards
Thomas

I’m guessing that what you’re hoping to do is get the longtable to span the full width of the page since you’ve got indentation down reasonably well. Alas, there is no * version of longtable analogous to tabular* that lets you specify a table width, so instead we need to do a bit of fiddling to make things work better by taking advantage of the \kill command in longtable that lets you create a line for spacing purposes that will not be printed.
Your first try might be to do something like this:
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\hspace{\linewidth}}\kill

but with \multicolumn all the extra space ends up going to the last column so you won’t get the appearance you were hoping for.¹
Instead we need to manually set our lengths. We’ll want to set the width of the first five columns to use all the space except for the last column and inter-column spaces, so we’ll create a new length and set it appropriately:
\newlength{\leftwidth}
\setlength{\leftwidth - \widthof{\textbf{of occurrence} % ❶
            - 4\arraycolsep % ❷
} 

We set our width to the width of the text “of occurrence” in boldface ❶ (we don’t need to replicate the whole \makecell construction here) and then also subtract out the width of the column separators ❷.²,³
Finally, we can do the following to set our column widths:
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\hspace{\leftwidth}}& \kill.

and you should get your desired alignment.


Although if you make the last column r instead of l it will be pretty close and actually might look best, but read on, since we want to come up with a general solution.
Why 4 times \arraycolsep? Because it’s defined as half the separation between columns and there’s also \arraycolsep of space on either side of the tabular so that’s two for the column separation plus one more for each side of the tabular.
Incidentally, I haven’t actually tested any of this, so it’s possible that there’s some additional space inserted because of the \makecell. If you get an overfull \hbox message with this, you can always just subtract the amount of the overfull \hbox as part of the setting above.

